# Top 5 Apps in UsageStats by PackageName

Tags: c#, linq

I am having an issue with LINQ in the context of the UsageStats class.
What I want to do is to get the top 5 packages used, and display the total sum of their time spent in foreground.

Where usageStatsList is my List result, I do this, which works fine:

`usageStatsList = usageStatsList.OrderBy(x => -(x.TotalTimeInForeground)).ToList();`

But of course, that isn't grouped by packagename, and individual packages can show up multiple times (I'm getting a week's worth of stats at once).
If I do this instead:

`usageStatsList.GroupBy(x => x.PackageName);`

I can group them but then I can't get the aggregated TotalTimeInForeground for the top apps.

Clearly it is a LINQ understanding issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var top5packages = usageStatsList
   .GroupBy(us => us.PackageName) // group stats by package
   .Select(g => new { // create group projection with aggregated time
        PackageName = g.Key,
        TotalTimeInForeground = g.Sum(us => us.TotalTimeInForeground)
   }) 
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalTimeInForeground) // order by total time       
   .Take(5); // return top 5 aggregated objects
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. The comments on each line were exactly what I needed to understand what I was doing wrong with my code.